# Can we install the stock ROM for P3110 on P3113? (7 inch Galaxy Tab 2)

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, rom, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7, stock-rom

The [P3113 model](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/galaxy-tab/GT-P3113TSYXAR-features) of the Galaxy Tab 2 hasn't yet received the [Android 4.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_4.1_Jelly_Bean_.28API_level_16.29) (Jelly Bean) update.

Is it possible to install the stock ROM for the [P3110](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Tab_series#Model_comparison) ROM (take from sammobile) on the P3113 device?

Comment: What's the difference in the two models? I would assume they are most likely not compatible. For example, Samsung Galaxy Nexus exists on different carriers, each is a different model and they are definitely not compatible with each other due to hardware differences for carriers (mainly CDMA vs GSM)

Comment: Another example would be the Wifi Xoom vs the 3G Xoom. Not compatible.

Comment: Agree with Bryan but I can't find much by Googling.  Comments seem to indicate it might work but nothing conclusive.

Comment: @BryanDenny - The p3113 is basically the p3110 (Tab 2 7.0 wifi-only) with a IR transmitter tacked on.  They're otherwise identical.  [CyanogenMod considers them to be the same device](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/P3110_Info).  The p3100 is the different one, which is the 3G version of the Tab 2 7.0.

Answer (score 1):

As a fellow Tab 2 user, I can quite happily tell you that any ROM for the GT-P3110, GT-P3113, or GT-P311X (Where X means 1 or 3) will work with essentially no issues, except you MIGHT lose IR capability. Other than that, Hunky-Dory!

Answer (score 0):

You can install it, but not everything will work properly. Most things should work, but not all.

Read the forum / thread from where you are downloading the ROM. If you are okay with a few things not working you can get it. Otherwise, you might want to wait till a ROM is ported out for your particular device.

You can read the XDA Forum thread *[What's the difference between 3110 and 3113?](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1652130)* to know what people have got working and what didn't work for them.